# I'm getting a small space below my nav

Tags: html, css

Why am i having a small space below my nav. i've set the margin of my nav to 0 and everything below it. still the space doesn't disappear. Here's my mark up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5</title>
      <style>
        body{
          width: 964px;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 0 auto;
          border: 1px solid black;
          font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        nav{
          width: 964px;
          background-color: blue;
          margin: 0;
        }

        nav ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

        nav ul li {
          display: inline-block;
          float: left;  
        }
        nav ul li a{
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 10px;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: blue;
        }

        nav ul li a:hover{
          background-color: #00a;
        }

        header{
          text-align: center;
          background-color: orange;
        }

        header h1{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 20px;
        }

        aside{
          float: left;
          width: 180px;
          height: 500px;
          background-color: red;
        }

        aside ul{
          list-style-type: none;
          padding-left: 15px;
        }

        aside ul li a{
          display: inline-block;
          text-decoration: none;
          background-color: #080;
          padding: 5px;
          width: 139px;
          color: white;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

        aside ul li a:hover{
          background-color: #050;
        }

        section{
          height: 500px;
          width: 964px;
          background-color: green;
        }

        footer{
          clear: both;
          background-color: yellow;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 5px;
        }

        .clearfix:after{
          content: " ";
          display: block;
          clear: both;
          visibility: hidden;
          line-height: 0;
          height: 0;
        }

        .clearfix{
          display: inline-block;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
      <nav class="clearfix">

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <aside>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Champions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Runes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skins</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Masteries</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    <section></section>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just want to eliminate the space between the nav and the aside but Putting margin: 0 on every container near the nav is not working.

Answer (score 6):

`:after` is a pseudo element which tells the browser to render a fake element inside the element *after* the content.

```css
.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

This is a block element, which means that it takes the full width of it's parent. However, the following rule makes the pseudo element's parent `.clearfix` into an inline-block element. This means that the element will only take up the mininum width that its content requires.

```css
.clearfix{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

You're seeing the space because inline-block elements are rendered inline as words, the white-space on either side of the element is rendered as a single space. You can solve this problem using either of the following methods.

- Remove the inline-block rule

  ([Demo](https://jsbin.com/quleroqiqi/edit?html,output))

  ```css
  .clearfix{
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Or, set the font size of the parent to 0, then set the font size for all direct children to the base font size.

  ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/nonagafina/edit?html,output))

  ```css
  body {
      font-size: 0;
  }
  body > * {
      font-size: 1rem;
  }
  ```

Comment: Does elements with inline-block display always cause annoying space there?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more in-depth explanation

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

when you remove the following attribute it gets rid of the space...

```
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
```